# Run Jquery on window resize

Tags: jquery

I am using j-query to set the height of a div same as width.It is now running on-load, but I want it to run on window resize.

I'm using this :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.source').each(function(){
    var currentWidth = $(this).width();
    $(this).height(currentWidth);
})
})
```

Comment: I wish down voters on my answer can read the link I've posted!-

Comment: name your anonymous function and use it on window resize too.. someone already answered in same fashion. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27441872/1577396).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just modification code of @Bala

```
// ready event
$(function () {
    function test() {
        $('.source').each(function () {
            var self = $(this);
            self.height(self.width());
            // but how the width is changing?
        });
    }();  //calling the function

    // resize event
    $(window).resize(test);
});
```

BTW, how the width is changing?

Comment: Width is given 33%, so it is changing according to the screen size.

Comment: @hussainnayani then I think it doesn't require jquery. it can be solved using css. Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frvjyeru/).

Answer (score 3):

You can use like this:

```
$(window).on('resize',function(){
$('.source').each(function(){
    var currentWidth = $(this).width();
    $(this).height(currentWidth);
})
}).resize();//runs at first load
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).resize(function(){
    //do things here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
    $('.source').each(function(){
        var currentWidth = $(this).width();
        $(this).height(currentWidth);
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.source').each(function(){
        var currentWidth = $(this).width();
        $(this).height(currentWidth);
    });
});
```

or even better, put the duplicate code into a separate function:

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
    changeWidth();
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    changeWidth();
});

function changeWidth() {
    $('.source').each(function(){
        var currentWidth = $(this).width();
        $(this).height(currentWidth);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use **[window.resize()](http://api.jquery.com/resize/)** event in jquery

```
function test() {
    $('.source').each(function () {
        var currentWidth = $(this).width();
        $(this).height(currentWidth);
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    test();
    $(window).resize(test);
});
```

Comment: Explain your answer please.

Comment: Bala, function declaration should be first. I edited. let me know, if I am wrong.

Comment: @Mr_Green that is not problem   see this http://designpepper.com/blog/drips/variable-and-function-hoisting

Comment: @Mr_Green If it is means Your are right *var test= function () {
    console.log("test not hoisted!");
}; * but i used like this *function test(){}*